# Gaining information from the form data in form_valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have to get some information from the form that has just been submitted. The form is a to put an event on a calendar.

I need to get the "Category" field, this is basically a name of the person the event includes.

From there I need to split the name into last and first and get their email from the user table. From there I will send them a email telling them they have been added to the calendar.

This is my `form_valid` function now:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    Event = form.save(commit=False)
    Event.created_by = self.request.user
    Event.save()
    send_mail(
        'test',
        'Is this really working?',
        'from@example.com',
        ['blah@gmail.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/calendar/')
```

How do I get information that has just been submitted in the form? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've just created a new Event instance with that data. So the data is in that Event, naturally.

You could also get it from the `form.cleaned_data` dict.